# Null Pointer Exception in Recursive and Iterative Binary search

Tags: java, recursion, nullpointerexception, iteration

The error comes at null pointer when I search for an element. It successfully accepts the inputs and displays the array but when I input the search element and press enter it displays error.

It shows null pointer exception with the following stack trace.

The error when is as follows when searching the element.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at BinarySearchClass.binarySearch(BinarySearchClass.java:26)
at BinarySearchIterative.main(BinarySearchIterative.java:25)
```

i.e; It says in this line

BinarySearchClass.java:26

```
while ((array[indexToLook] != search) && (maxIndex > minIndex)) {
```

and this line in the other file

BinarySearchIterative.java:25

```
int found = BSI.binarySearch(search);
```

Please help me correct it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinarySearchClass {

    private  Integer[] array;

    public  BinarySearchClass(int size){
        this.array = new Integer[size];
    }

    public BinarySearchClass(){
        this(100); //default size of array.
    }

    public  int binarySearch(int search){

        int maxIndex = size()-1;
        int minIndex = 0;

        int indexToLook = (int) Math.floor((minIndex + maxIndex)/2);
        while ((array[indexToLook] != search) && (maxIndex > minIndex)) {
            if(array[indexToLook] > search) {
                maxIndex = indexToLook - 1;
            }
            else{
                minIndex = indexToLook + 1; 
            }
            indexToLook = (int) Math.floor((minIndex+maxIndex/2));
        }
        if(array[indexToLook] == search)
            return indexToLook;

        return -1;
    }

    public  int binarySearch( int search, int minIndex, int maxIndex){
        if (minIndex == maxIndex){
            if(array[minIndex] == search) 
                return minIndex;
            return -1;
        }
        int indexToLook = (int) Math.floor((minIndex + maxIndex)/2);
        if(array[indexToLook] == search){
            return indexToLook;
        }
        if(array[indexToLook] < search)
            return binarySearch( search, indexToLook+1, maxIndex );
        return binarySearch( search, minIndex, indexToLook-1);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.deepToString(this.array);
    }

    private  int size() {
        int i = 0;
        while (((array[i] != null) && i < array.length) ) {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

class BinarySearchIterative:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinarySearchIterative   {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BinarySearchClass BSI = new BinarySearchClass(10);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Iterative");

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements: ");
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[size];
        int i;
        for(i =0; i<=size-1; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter the element " + i + " :");
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The elements are");
        for(i=0; i<=size-1; i++){
            System.out.print("[" + array[i] + "]");
        }
        int search = 0;
        System.out.println("\nEnter the element to search");
        search = scan.nextInt();
        int found = BSI.binarySearch(search);
        if (found > -1)
        {
            System.out.println("The element " + search +  " is found in location " + (found+1) );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Element " + search + " not found");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT (@Paul):
Since the array you want to perform a binary search on is already given in `BinarySearchIterative`, I'd recommend this approach instead of yours:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinarySearchClass {
    public static int binarySearch(int search , int[] array){

        int maxIndex = size()-1;
        int minIndex = 0;

        int indexToLook = (int) Math.floor((minIndex + maxIndex)/2);
        while ((array[indexToLook] != search) && (maxIndex > minIndex)) {
            if(array[indexToLook] > search) {
                maxIndex = indexToLook - 1;
            }
            else{
                minIndex = indexToLook + 1; 
            }
            indexToLook = (int) Math.floor((minIndex+maxIndex/2));
        }
        if(array[indexToLook] == search)
            return indexToLook;

        return -1;
    }

    public static int binarySearch( int search, int minIndex, int maxIndex , int[] arr){
        if (minIndex == maxIndex){
            if(array[minIndex] == search) 
                return minIndex;
            return -1;
        }
        int indexToLook = (int) Math.floor((minIndex + maxIndex)/2);
        if(array[indexToLook] == search){
            return indexToLook;
        }
        if(array[indexToLook] < search)
            return binarySearch( search, indexToLook+1, maxIndex );
        return binarySearch( search, minIndex, indexToLook-1);
    }
}

class BinarySearchIterative:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinarySearchIterative   {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ...
        int found = BinarySearchClass.binarySearch(search ,  array);
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that the input-array must be **sorted** in order to perform a binary search, which isn't ensured by your code. And there's a more general design-problem with your code. `BinarySearchClass` shouldn't store any arrays itself and only provide the utility-methods to search an array (with `static` methods, like in my example). This would be the general approach of programming: modularization. Each Class should only provide functionality for one specific purpose or should only hold data that represents a single data-set and provide functionality to handle this data. Have a look a general coding-style guide (there are tons of books, webmaterial, etc. on this topic).

Comment: pretty common mistake: you use an `Integer[]` (note that `Integer` is an Object!!!) and never intialize it with values, thus all values are `null` and comparing these values will result in a `NullPointerException`. Initialize the array properly and things should work just fine.

Comment: since I am new to programming ... can you tell me how to initialize them properly?

Comment: you mean i should change the integer[] as int[] ?...... I have used Integer, rather than int, so that we can do null checks to see if data is present at a particular index or not.  it will be hard to see if a 0 was really inserted as part of data, or it is the initialized 0 as java automatically initializes int...

Comment: just assign some value to the single values Since you want to use the array for binary-search, you should use sorted values. Either directly get the array as a constructor-parameter, or generate them in the constructor. Just make sure that the array holds a value for each index. As for the change from `int[]` to `Integer[]` that would just be a workaround to solve the problem with the `Exception`. If you want to search the range, you'll have to initialize it properly anyways.

Comment: Thanks!... but I still couldn't figure out this way so I went on and implemented method() and It worked. 
But I still would like to do it this way and as I couldn't get it, will you please just edit those lines which will make this one work? would help me in learning... Thanks in advance

Comment: its a bit late now, I'll do that tomorrow (in about 8 hrs from now)

Comment: awesome....  Thanks.... means a lot!...

Comment: yeah I just saw.. and it makes sense.. thank you.